# changing javascript class background color

Tags: javascript, css

I Have this Javascript....

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('metro tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

and the class metro tile-area-darkCrimson is defined as in CSS....

```
.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f255b !important;


    transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;

}
```

Why does the background color not change even though the rest of the function works ? Much help appreciated in advance.

Cheers,
Greg.

EDIT ---------

I now have this on advice from helpful people

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').addClass('color-red');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

and have added into the CSS this ...

.color-red { background :#f36c20; }

But still not working any more help really appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try without the !important tag?

Change this:

```
background-color: #1f255b !important;
```

Into this:

```
background-color: #1f255b;
```

Comment: HAH ! AWESOME IT WORKED !  nice one very keen eye mate !

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the dot notation of class. Change this line

```
 $('metro tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
```

to

```
$('.metro tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
```

Comment: thanks but still didn't work .... is 'background-color' supposed to be 'backgroundColor' ?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('metro tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
```

to

```
 $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
```

Comment: thanks but still didn't work .... is 'background-color' supposed to be 'backgroundColor' ?

Comment: It is `background-color`

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the . for the metro class in jQuery

```
$('.metro tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color','#f36c20');
```

Also it would be better to add a class instead of using .css in jQuery

```
$('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').addClass('color-red');
```

and in your css make class

```
.color-red { background :#f36c20; }
```

`

Comment: I have this <script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').addClass('color-red');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);
   
});
</script>

Comment: its because when you use .css method its adds style inline to the element so its get top pirority so it will be applied but when you use .addClass the styles of the class must be overriding so you have to select the parent of the element and then add style like .parent .color-red or .parent .parent .color-red

Comment: could you provide an example of this friend ?

Comment: also you can use !important if everything fails but its not a good practice